# Why can't 1 from the type object be cast to a double

Tags: c#, listbox

**When I want to cast 1 to double, it does not work. When I cast 1.0 to double it works. Why?**

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    ArrayList liste1 = new ArrayList();
    liste1.Add(1);
    liste1.Add("Hallo");
    liste1.Add(2.5);

    double num = (double)liste1[0] + (double)liste1[2];

    Console.WriteLine(num);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I change `liste1.Add(1);` to `liste1.Add(1.0);` it works. Why does it work with `1.0` and not with `1`?

It works too **when I first cast liste1[0] to an int, and then to a double. Can you tell me why, please?**

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayList` holds objects. If you add an `int` it gets "boxed" into an object and can only be "unboxed" back to `int` - not `double`.

[MSDN: boxing & unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Because if you type `1` then it will be an integer value, not a double. Integer cannot be **cast** to double, it can be only **converted** to double which is different operation even though it looks the same in code. So if you want it to be working with integer `1`, you have to cast it to `int` and then convert into `double`:

```
(double)(int)liste1[0]
```

Or use `Convert.ToDouble` which probably does something like that inside:

```
((IConvertible)liste1[0]).ToDouble();
```

Comment: Or use "Convert": `Convert.ToDouble(liste1[0])`

Comment: True, more elegant way would be: `double num = Convert.ToDouble(liste1[0]) + Convert.ToDouble(liste1[2]);`

Comment: @KooKiz three seconds ahead of me.. nice! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in detail [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx), on Eric Lippert's excellent blog.

In short, it's due to C#'s cast operator meaning different things in different contexts. It's best to think of int as having an [implicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) allowing it to be *converted* to double, but if the type isn't known at compile time to be an int, this won't be run. After all, `object` does **not** have an implicit (or explicit) conversion operator capable of converting that type, and that's what you're seemingly trying to do.

Now if desired some more work could be done behind the scenes to determine if there is a way of converting it, but as this is nontrivial it's best left to a versatile helper method like `Convert.ToDouble(object)`.

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList indexer returns an object. C# cannot cast from an object to a double. Its all to do with runtime type conversion and boxing.

This should work:

```
double num = (double)(int)liste1[0] +(double)liste1[2];
```